# Oracle ADF Authorization and role-based pages

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

I would like to create an adf application , this web application will have different user roles like manager,normal user and admin .
First, I want to check users when they try to login into system by getting users info from database. I mean authorization should be provided by adf security from database Users table
Then according to this user's roles, specific web pages should be shown to logged users. Users should see only pages that its responsible pages.

I dont know how to do it, I need your guidance

Answer (score 1):

Users and roles are  Weblogic's concern (presuming you are using Weblogic), you may find a great example on how to load users and roles from the database here:

http://soadev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/sqlauthenticator-simply-best.html

For enabling security in an ADF application, I presume you have found already enough info, but just in case:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFFD/adding_security.htm#ADFFD877